# Setting up a home server to retrieve mp3 urls

Tags: python, django, url, server, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an amazon Alexa skill to stream our music from the web.

I would like to have a database of mp3s that is accessible by my app but the mp3s should not be public for download but only for streaming. Thus spotify or soundcloud don't seem to me like good options.

I was thinking to set up a home server where to physically store the mp3s thus having easy access to their urls to pass to the Alexa's AudioPlayer, but I have little experience in setting up servers.

- Do you have any alternative workaround suggestions for my issue?
- In case the home server might seem a reasonable option to you, where can I start to understand how to do that?

(I code mainly in Python and I know very little of Django)

Comment: Server setup is not a topic for SO. It is a website about programming.

Comment: thanks for your answer Klaus. Could you point me to a more dedicated forum/website to post this question?thanks.